# correctly regress dunif() function

Tags: r

I am struggling with correctly applying dunif(). I need to make a linear regression but I don't get any values.
I used the following code:

```
set.seed(69)
n <- 1000
e <- dnorm(n,0,0.1)
x <- dunif(n,0,1)

y =  5*x + e
fit <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(fit)
```

and I got this as output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
ALL 1 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)        0        NaN     NaN      NaN
x                 NA         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
```

Can anyone help me? I'm a complete beginner so any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You created only a single value.  Please check your `e`, `x` and `y`, If you check `dnorm`, `x-> vector of quantiles` .  You just provided a single `n`

Comment: I think you should have used `runif(n, 0, 1)` instead of `dunif(n, 0, 1)`.

Comment: And also `rnorm(n,0,0.1)`

Comment: @user2554330, post as answer? (Or vote to close as typo ...)

Comment: ahhh I see now. It worked perfectly fine with rnorm and runif. Thanks guys!